# push string to a vector and convert to int

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I would like to read a string of digits then push the digits to a vector one by one.

```
string _inValue = "12345";
vector<int> _value;

void superint::setVector()
{
for(int i=0; i < _inValue.length(); ++i)
{
    _value.push_back(_inValue[i]);
}
}
```

What I do is this: I will push_back the ASCII value of `'1'` (`49`). I want it to have the value `1`.

Is the best way to just use `_inValue[i]-48`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to subtract the value of the ASCII '0':

```
_value.push_back(_inValue[i]-'0');
```

That is much more descriptive than just using a magic number like 48.